# eloquent query performance vs PDO

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have simplest query with count:
`Client::where('active', 1)->count();`

There's only 20 rows in that `clients` table but query takes over 1 second to complete. I've checked and replaced this line with simple PDO query and it took a lot less (~0.015s).

Is it normal for Eloquent to be so slow with relatively simple queries? Is there any way to make it more efficient? I've googled around but all the information I could find regards optimizing queries for big data sets.

Comment: Are you looking at the query time specifically, or the time for the entire request? Most frameworks are going to take longer to process requests in dev/debug mode due to extra profiling and such that won't be happening when it's running in production.

Comment: I was measuring only the query time (response timing was what got me bothered). I've used various methods and combinations - with debug mode on/off, using Clockwork API, using simple `microtime`, on localhost and remote server, and so on. There was some variety in timing but the difference between Eloquent query and PDO was always huge.

Comment: Can you log or view the exact SQL that Eloquent is executing and verify that it is the same as your PDO query?

Comment: Yes, it's the same query.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to inspect your queries and check if it's really Eloquent's that is slowing down your execution time.

It's fairly impossible that a simple query with 20 results take so long (you told 1s).

Eloquent isn't very fast, since you are using a Query Builder class to generate the query, then after the results are available, it will hydrate a collection of models.

Most of the time the cause for slowness on Eloquent is lazy-loaded Relationships, custom attributes or mutators, for example:

Your main query is just 20 rows. But after it, you are calling a relationship that wasn't eager loaded, that have 100 results for each row of the main query. This will be slow and inefficient.

Custom attributes that make queries and are attached to the results can also slow down.

It's really hard to tell you what's the cause of your slowness without seeing a piece of code. Tell me if you provide some functional sample so I can try to find the reason.

---

**Edit:** Just FYI, one of our applications (pure html + laravel), renders a list page with more then **500 results**, in **1 second**, and isn't a simple query. The query count is 25, and the total queries time is 250ms without caching.